# When using < operator swift goes over specified number before exiting

Tags: swift, operators, swift2, xcode7

I am currently learning swift/iOS programing. When I use a < operator and do something like: x < y, x will go past y before exiting. Is there a way around this so it stops as it hits y rather than going over?
Any and all help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

So when I press my **AddBtnPressed** button it adds **firstNum** and **secondNum** storing it in **sumNum**. Say **firstNum = 995**, **secondNum = 15**, when I hit my button it will hit **1010** instead of exiting and then if I hit my button again after that it will then exit after its already gone over.
Hope this makes sense!

The user inputs a number hits **play** which takes you to a second screen that says **"press add to add"** you press the **Add** button and it reveals an equation of **0 + (user input number) = x**. and every time you press the **Add** button it adds the user number to the previous sum until it hits 999 then its supposed to take you back to the main screen.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var firstNum = 0
var secondNum = 0
var sumNum = 0
var maxNum = 900


// First Screen
@IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var userNum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var play: UIButton!


// Second Screen
@IBOutlet weak var pressAddToAdd: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var AddBtn: UIButton!


// Thrird Screen
@IBOutlet weak var ContSum: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var addUserNum: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sum: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mathSymbols: UILabel!



@IBAction func playBtnPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    if userNum.text != nil && userNum.text != "" {

        userNum.hidden = true
        logo.hidden = true
        play.hidden = true

        pressAddToAdd.hidden = false
        AddBtn.hidden = false
    }   
}

@IBAction func AddBtnPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    if sumNum <= maxNum {

        // Hide 2nd screen
        pressAddToAdd.hidden = true


        // Reveal 3rd screen
        ContSum.hidden = false
        addUserNum.hidden = false
        sum.hidden = false
        mathSymbols.hidden = false


        // Variables
        firstNum = sumNum
        secondNum = Int (userNum.text!)!
        sumNum = firstNum + secondNum


        // Imput Variables into textFields
        addUserNum.text = "\(secondNum)"
        sum.text = "\(sumNum)"
        ContSum.text = "\(sumNum - secondNum)"

    } else {

    // Restart
        firstNum = 0
        secondNum = 0
        sumNum = 0

        ContSum.hidden = true
        addUserNum.hidden = true
        sum.hidden = true
        mathSymbols.hidden = true
        AddBtn.hidden = true

        userNum.hidden = false
        logo.hidden = false
        play.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Show a standalone example of your issue.

Comment: You need to show your whole class. I would strongly guess the first time you press your button sumNum is 0, which would evaluate to true and go into your if statement. Also, it would be helpful to hear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluation your total outside of your conditional

```
sumNum += Int(userNum.text!)!

if sumNum <= 999 {
...
}
```

Comment: Ah that was it! Thanks Strat!!

Answer (score 0):

operator < is nothing but less than. less than can be true or false. expression x < y is evaluated as value of type Bool

```
// "do something like: x < y"

2 < 3      // true
"a" < "b"  // true
var x = 0
var y = 1
x++ < y     // true
print(x, y) // 1 1
--x < y     // true
print(x, y) // 0 1
```

Comment: Right so if x < y once x is > than y it should evaluate to false and should exit the if statement right? I know C will exit before it prints. Does swift print x so to speak and then equal false and then exit? hope that makes sense.

Comment: < operator works the same way as in C. x < y is an expression. the expression is evaluated as true or false. now i see your updated question ... i am going to check what is your problem

Comment: Yep that was what it was! Thanks!!